# How do I return floating point values in NASM?

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, nasm, x86-64

I'm trying to return a floating point value in **NASM**.  It always displays "-nan".

Using:

- **NASM** version 2.10.09 compiled on Dec 29 2013
- **g++** 4.8

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" double _main();

int main()
{
    std::cout << _main() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**_main.asm**:

```
global _main

segment .data
val: dq 123.321

segment .text
_main:

    PUSH rbp
    MOV rbp, rsp

    FINIT
    FLD qword [val]

    MOV rsp, rbp
    POP rbp

RET
```

If someone has some tutorials and/or instruction, example, uses online for NASM please link them.

Comment: Have you checked your platform's calling conventions for `extern "C"`?

Comment: Here is a simple way: write a C function that returns a `double`, compile it to assembly, and in your own assembly function, mimic the last instructions of the assembly code, that will undoubtedly respect the ABI of your platform.

Comment: x86-64 uses xmm registers for floats. See the ABI documentation, instead of trying to reverse engineer compiler generated code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`movsd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html) to load a scalar `double` into an XMM register.

For the files:

**caller.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" double asmfunc();

double val = 123.321;

double dubidoo ()
{
    return val;
}

int main ()
{
    cout << "dubidoo: " << dubidoo() << endl;
    cout << "asmfunc: " << asmfunc() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**callee.asm:**

```
segment .data
    val: dq 123.321

section .text
global asmfunc

asmfunc:
    movsd    xmm0, [val]
    ret
```

**make & run:**

```
nasm -felf64 callee.asm
g++ Wl,callee.o caller.cpp
./a.out
```

Comment: What is the difference between "movups xmm0, [val]" and "movq xmm0, [val]"?

Comment: @KarloMiličević `movups` is [Move Unaligned Packed Single-Precision Floating- Point Values](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_208.html) and `movq` is [Move Quadword](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_201.html)